# Empty DIV height IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml, internet-explorer-7

**UPDATE 1:**

I've found that when removing `width:100%` from the div, I get the results I want interms of it having 0 height if it contains no content.  However, I need the div to have a width of 100%, which for some reason is forcing it to have a height without content.

Here is a jsfiddle of the problem.  You will only see the problem if you go to the following link with IE7, maybe on IE6 and below.

http://jsfiddle.net/RQeeg/2/

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have an empty div which has a height for some reason.

On Chrome, the div does not appear at all unless it contains content.  IE7 on the other hand shows the div even if it has no content.

So basically, I want it to have a height of 0px if it is empty, and automatically adjust it's height if it has content.  Which is exactly how it behaves if it does not have a width of 100%.

Comment: my telepathy is telling me that you have some issues with invisible code. You need to make the code visible, and then change the css.

Comment: @jball, IE7 doesn't have to render the `div` like chrome.  I want it to have a height of 0px if it is empty, and automatically adjust it's height if it has content.

Comment: i don't have IE installed to test, but try div `height: 0px auto;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update after the revelation that you're using `position: fixed`:

To support IE7 here, you must use two `div`s. I'm reasonably sure there's no way round this (unless you'd prefer to stick with one `div` and use a JavaScript fix).

**See:**
Without content: http://jsfiddle.net/r3P8D/2/
With content: http://jsfiddle.net/r3P8D/3/

The reason that this bug happens is because once you add certain properties such as `width: <not auto>` or `position: fixed`, you trigger [`hasLayout` on the element](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html). As soon as you trigger `hasLayout`, this bug happens.

Because you require `position: fixed` ([..which doesn't even work in IE6](http://caniuse.com/css-fixed), but I digress), there is no way to avoid `hasLayout`, and hence no way to avoid this bug.

So, I've given you the best workaround I can think of.

---

**Old answer:**

> However, I need the div to have a
>   width of 100%

Simply don't use `width: 100%`.

The `div` will then have the default `width` value, which is `auto`, so it will take "the full available width". `width: auto` is *not the same* as `width: 100%`, but for the purposes of this question, it looks the same visually.

Check this in Chrome and IE6/7 (without content): http://jsfiddle.net/r3P8D/
Check this in Chrome and IE6/7 (with content): http://jsfiddle.net/r3P8D/1/

From my understanding of your question, this is exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I didn't point out that the div has a `position:fixed`, which is why I have the `width:100%`.

Comment: You should have included the fact that you're using `position:fixed` in your test case - that completely changes things, and isn't just some throwaway detail. You did say you need `width: 100%`, but you didn't state *why*. Most of the time, `width: auto` does the same thing. Sigh. I will update my answer.

Comment: Maybe my English is bad, but people don't say they "need" something for no reason.  Even if the position:fixed is not there, the problem is still a problem if the width:100% is used.  As I said I need the width, should that not have been respected, instead of just telling me to get rid of it?

Comment: The assumption I made was that you need a full width `div`, not that you need `width: 100%` - and that you simply were somehow not aware of `width: auto`. As I explained, `width: auto` and `width: 100%` are subtly different (but often appear to be the same). Anyway, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoying IE bug.

I think I've got round it in the past with:

```
div{
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:0;
    display: inline;   
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomgrohl/YfbJt/

If this has affected your layout it might be best to use a class, which gets added when you add content to the div (if your adding it dynamically):

```
div
{
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

div.active
{
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: How is the content being added to the div? What styling does it have in the first place? (Might be best to add your answer to your question, might be easier to read).

Comment: I got that jsFiddle up in IE7 and it worked, have you cleared your cache?

Comment: You've just repeated the same thing you said previously. The jsfiddle I did has the width at 100% and works.

Answer (score 0):

I think IE 7 gives a default height to  unless you provide a value.

Try setting the height to 0px.

Comment: I tried that and yes, it got rid of the height, but then when I add content to it, the content is not shown, because it sticks to 0px.

Comment: I have now and it doesn't work, i.e. I still shows the empty div.

Comment: @oshi please edit your original question to be more specific; your original post sounds like you just want to set div `height: 0px;`

Answer (score -3):

Add this to the beginning of your CSS File:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

This applies standard rules to elements, and eliminates cross-browser inconsistencies.

---

If it still gives you an error, try adding this under the reset:

```
div{
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
}
```